# Pay, or partial pay in Bitcoin

Tags: salary

If I wanted to be paid or partially paid in Bitcoin, but my employer is not participating, is there a secure online service where I could authorize all or a portion of my pay to be sent and converted to Bitcoin?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you need is [BitWage](https://www.bitwage.com/); it does exactly what you ask: get paid fully or partially in bitcoin without involving your employer. There might be other services like that.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use bitwage to do this, you could just easily link your bank account to coinbase or circle and choose how much you want to buy after your paycheck clears into your account. You can even allow your account to buy X amount of dollars worth every week or something like that. Bitwage, in my opinion, doesn't really make sense when you can just control how much you want to buy each week or 2 weeks after you get your pay check.